# ParseError: undefined entity while parsing XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml.etree, character-entities

I have a big XML file with several `article` nodes. I have included only one with the problem. I try to parse it in Python to filter some data and I get the error

```
File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: undefined entity &Ouml;: line 90, column 17
```

Sample of the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp.dtd">
    <dblp>
        <article mdate="2019-10-25" key="tr/gte/TR-0146-06-91-165" publtype="informal">
            <author>Alejandro P. Buchmann</author>
            <author>M. Tamer &Ouml;zsu</author>
            <author>Dimitrios Georgakopoulos</author>
            <title>Towards a Transaction Management System for DOM.</title>
            <journal>GTE Laboratories Incorporated</journal>
            <volume>TR-0146-06-91-165</volume>
            <month>June</month>
            <year>1991</year>
            <url>db/journals/gtelab/index.html#TR-0146-06-91-165</url>
        </article>
    </dblp>
```

From my search in Google, I found that this kind of error appears if you have issues in the node names. However, the line with the error is the second `author`, in the text.

This is my Python code

```
with open('xaa.xml', 'r') as xml_file:
    xml_tree = etree.parse(xml_file)
```

Comment: As the error message tells you, `&0uml;` is not a standard XML entity so as it stands your XML isn’t valid, hence the error. See https://www.xml.com/pub/a/98/08/xmlqna2.html not sure if you can declare them to ElementTree outside the XML file.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration of the `Ouml` entity is presumably in the DTD (dblp.dtd), but ElementTree does not support external DTDs. ElementTree only recognizes entities declared directly in the XML file (in the "internal subset"). This is a working example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE dblp [
<!ENTITY Ouml 'Ö'>
]>
<dblp>
  <article mdate="2019-10-25" key="tr/gte/TR-0146-06-91-165" publtype="informal">
    <author>Alejandro P. Buchmann</author>
    <author>M. Tamer &Ouml;zsu</author>
    <author>Dimitrios Georgakopoulos</author>
    <title>Towards a Transaction Management System for DOM.</title>
    <journal>GTE Laboratories Incorporated</journal>
    <volume>TR-0146-06-91-165</volume>
    <month>June</month>
    <year>1991</year>
    <url>db/journals/gtelab/index.html#TR-0146-06-91-165</url>
  </article>
</dblp>
```

To parse the XML file in the question without errors, you need a more powerful XML library that supports external DTDs. [lxml](http://lxml.de/index.html) is a good choice for that.

Answer (score 0):

The Oouml looks like a standard html5 entity. It may help to convert those to their unicode characters before running the xml parser. In python3.4+ you can use `html.unescape` for that.

```
from html import escape, unescape
textXML = re.sub("\\&\\w+\\;", lambda x: escape(unescape(x.group(0))), text)
```